# Need to find element element with inner text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a table with rows of records. I have ID "171485824993" as my data to look and need to get the text value "New, Jersey" and click on the text as its a link. 
There will be more than 1 record similar to this and need to loop till I find the correct row that has the ID I am looking for.

```
<div layout="row" class="table2Row ng-scope layout-row" ng-repeat="state in fullList">
  <div class="flex-inline top-bottom-margin-15 flex" flex="">
    <a ng-click="$ctrl.viewDetails(st)" flex="30" aria-label="St" tabindex="0" class="ng-binding flex-30">New, York</a>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex-10" flex="10">NY</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex-10" flex="10">M</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex-15" flex="15">01/28/1991</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex" flex="">171485421586</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex" flex="">M4398-1</p>
  </div>

<div layout="row" class="table2Row ng-scope layout-row" ng-repeat="state in fullList">
  <div class="flex-inline top-bottom-margin-15 flex" flex="">
    <a ng-click="$ctrl.viewDetails(st)" flex="30" aria-label="St" tabindex="0" class="ng-binding flex-30">New, Jersey</a>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex-10" flex="10">NJ</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex-10" flex="10">M</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex-15" flex="15">03/28/1996</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex" flex="">171485824993</p>
    <p class="small ng-binding flex" flex="">M4398-1</p>
  </div>
```

I tried the following code but getting error as invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

```
List <WebElement> studentCount= driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".table2Row"));
for (int i=0; i<studentCount.size();i++) {
    String studentName= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".table2Row:nth-of-type(i) p:nth-of-type(4)")).getText();
    if (studentName.equals("171485824993"))
        System.out.println (studentName);
        break;          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `xpath`?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='171485824993']/preceding-sibling::a"));
```

This will give you the previous sibling with `<a>` tag to the element with the ID.

Comment: Thanks @Guy for the help, I used my css code by correcting the "+i+". But I am using your code in some other areas where I was looking for it for some time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the `i` like you would any other string:

```
String studentName= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".table2Row:nth-of-type(" + i + ") p:nth-of-type(4)")).getText();
```

Comment: Hi @BoltClock, Thanks for the reply. Actually I found that I have missed those quotes after I posted the question. It is working fine now.